# When making a redirection in aframe virtual reality mode, it freezes for 2 to 5 seconds

Tags: javascript, aframe, virtual-reality

Any way that I can do the redirection without freezing, or in any case that a message appears to the user that he is being redirected?

I tested in Meta Quest Browser and Firefox Reality.

I have tried these two forms of redirection:

```
window.location.replace("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page");
window.location.href = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page";
```

I share the test link:

Live site: https://heavenly-tangy-address.glitch.me

Code: https://glitch.com/edit/#!/heavenly-tangy-address

Answer (score 0):

I find this solution to work well.

What consists of leaving the vr mode and then just doing the redirection

```
const sceneEl = document.querySelector('a-scene');
if (sceneEl.is('vr-mode')) sceneEl.exitVR();
window.location.href = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page";
```

I think this is a good solution to avoid screen freezing